# How to reveal pppoe password behind asterisk in my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, passwords

I lost my pppoe password, so I want to recover it from my router configuration setting but I am not succeeding after my lot of research on Internet. I used many password revealer tools but it can't help me actually they reveal's my password but after revealing another asterisk password appears

Before Reveal my password looks like :- ●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●●

After reveal using any software my password turns to : *********************

I need my password in number like 12345 ....

so please please please help me ......

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model of this router?

Comment: FTTH Broadband Router - GPON ONT

Comment: MTNL FTTH - Fibre to the Home Broadband service is using GPON ONT as its Router.

Comment: Often you can backup settings and then check the password. With TP Link for example you can and then decode the base64 encrypted password to see what the actual password is.

Comment: If you can inspect the traffic on the WAN link (e.g. between the router and ONT) and you can force the authentication method to PAP in the router you will see the password in plain text during the handshake.

Answer (score 11):

In inspect element mode of the browser and while you are on the password field change `input type = password` to `input type = text` :), man who would've thought hacking WiFi would be that easy through the browser.

Comment: a "modern" browser :D

Comment: well, that would work usually but as the OP said the revealed password is just asterisks, since the value of the html element you are referring to is actually asterisks.

Answer (score 4):

Open the router configuration page using a browser like Google Chrome or Firefox. Right click the password box, select Inspect element.

Search for `<input type="password"....` and remove that bit. It should show the password in plain text

[image]

Comment: Nice try, but given that he wrote: After reveail using any software, my password turns to: ************* it will do the same with your code.

Comment: @LPChip yeah I noticed, but he mentioned "password revealer tools" which usually do not work well with browser based pages. If he mentions this doesn't work, I'll remove

Comment: By the nature of how some routers work, I'm fairly sure it won't work. They replace the password with 12 to 18 *'s to hide the length of the password, so people can't guess the password.

Answer (score 1):

A PPPoE password is usually the one from your internet provider. I would contact them so they can reset the password. You can then change it there to what they've given you.

It is unlikely you will be able to "hack" this password, as the router will not show it to you, but will only allow you to change it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Passwords can be extracted from some routers by making a settings backup and decoding it.

I can't provide you with precise instructions because you haven't specified you router's model, but what you want to do is to download a backup of your settings. Then you'll have to search for a tool or website that will allow you to decode backup file. The password should be readable in the output.

Comment: My routers encoding is Base64, They are usually not encrypted with password so it could be Md5 as well but thats it!

Answer (score 1):

I Know how to reveal that password in GPON ont, i was recently looking for PPPoE password too, i'm trying to change html code in inspect element, not working. I'm trying to access telnet on router, not working too, then i found 1 app for Windows, [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/router_password_recovery.html) it's called RouterPassView.

To make this app work, you need to backup your router setting first. After backup, you'll have `config.cfg` file.

Next, after you download RouterPassView, open it, and import your router backup file called `config.cfg`
 file, after that you'll see a lot of xml data like this [image: this]

Then, find your PPPoE username and password using `CTRL+F` In this case, im using keyword "pass"

When you find it, you'll see

```
<Username dv="" ml="64" rw="RW" t="string" v="(YOUR_PPPOE_USERNAME)"></Username>
```

and

```
<Password dv="" ml="64" rw="RW" t="string" v="(YOUR_PPPOE_PASS)"></Password>
```

Screenshot: [image: pic]

There is the PPPoE password. Goodluck

*Tested on GPON ONT Alcatel Lucent G-240W-A